# How can I pass the FQDN hostname to systemd?

Tags: systemd, amazon-ec2, hostname

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system in AWS. The `%H` flag in `systemd` is replaced with the hostname as expected, but I need a way to capture the output of `hostname --fqdn`.

`%H` outputs `ip-10-0-0-188` on my instance, but I want to get the equivalent of `hostname --fqdn` which outputs `ip-10-0-0-188.ec2.internal`. I am avoiding hardcoding `%H.ec2.internal` in case this ever changes in the future.

What is the best way to achieve this?